# html5 geolocation tracking

Tags: geolocation

I am new to html 5 geolocation,  Is there any site or examples  where it shows how, i can use html geolocation api to track the location of other devices. Also, for example how can i use use HTML5  geolocation to find the nearest car dealer say 5 or 10 miles from me?
Any examples sample would be really helpfull.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to tracking devices, but i've been writing something that might help with the second part of your question.

```
    //check browser support
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
    //do the geolocation stuff
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        //make a string out of the coordinates
        var initloc_str = position.coords.latitude + ', ' + position.coords.longitude;
        //pass it to a function that searches for donut shops near the coordinates
        donutSearch(initloc_str);
    });
    } else { // if no browser support, error message or whatever
```

My donut shop search function is based on the local search in Google's Ajax search API, I found [this article on webmonkey](http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/get_local_search_results_with_google_maps_and_ajax_apis/) helpful for that bit. That API was recently deprecated but I haven't figured out how to do local search with their new Custom Search API yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can register a function for tracking positions of a user:

```
var watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {  
  console.log(position.coords.latitude);
  console.log(position.coords.longitude);
});
```

And you can unregister:

```
navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchId);
```

Answer (score -1):

This [site](http://locationdetection.mobi) will give you a awesome overview of the HTML5 geolocation Capability.